# Process contact from outlook csv

Tags: c#, csv, outlook

I want to import contacts from outlook csv to my program. I don't want to renovate a wheel. May be someone did it already?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  + http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a CVS file is simply a text file in which data is separated by a tab character as delimiter. Therefore you can easily read the file using:

```
 var Data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("CVS File");
```

Then make up a model for the file:

```
 class Model{
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string First_Name {get; set;}
    // bla bla
  }

 foreach(var i in Data.Skip(1)) {
      var Temp = i.Splite('\t');
      Model model = new Model{ Email = Temp[0], First_Name = Temp [1]};
 }
```

or you could read the first line by removing the `Skip(1)` to find the position for different headers.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I know how to deal with csv. I thought may be someone made all those links between fields in outlook export file and what are they mean.